# How do you Use jQuery with Node Express App POST

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to simply use jQuery in my npm project on the server side.
I want to be able to change the values in my HTML/set them via my database.
But i cannot for the life of me figure out how to declare or require the needed variables. Please help and explain!

```js
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var JSDOM = jsdom.JSDOM;
var window = new JSDOM("${__dirname}/homepage/index.html").window;
global.document = window.document;
const $ = require( "jquery" )( window );
//Test upload to mongodb
//Get Random Index of 'Released Pokemon' For It's Pokedex #ID
const releasedPokemon = [1,4,7,10,13,16,19,21,23,25,27,29,32,35,37,39,41,43,46,48,50,52,54,56,58,60,63,66,69,72,74,77];
app.post('/catch', async function(req, res) {
    //Catch random pokemon
    $(document).ready('#catchPokemon').hide(300);
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * releasedPokemon.length);
    const dex = releasedPokemon[index];
    const pokemon = await PokeAPI.pokeAPI(dex)
    console.log(pokemon);
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/catch">
                        <button style="background-color: Transparent;" onclick="catchPokemon()">
                            <img type="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/zs02wMs.png" alt="Catch Pokemon"
                                width="100" height="100">
                            </button>
                    </form>
```

Comment: uhm... javascript on your server can't show/hide stuff on the client. it can't interact with the dom at all once it's sent to the client.

Comment: I may not be explaining it correctly, im pretty sure you can change innerHTML and set it to somthing pulled from a database.... Has to be a thing.

Another way I could try is send the data from  my server after I have fetched the values from mongoose over to my script file somehow. Can I capture it and send it via post and jQuery?

Comment: something like this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643522/how-to-change-front-end-html-using-node-js

Comment: Your client can send an http request to your server. Your server can respond to that request with text, and your client can then do things with that text, such as render it as an html page, or pass it to a fetch callback that then inserts it into an existing page.

Comment: yes! I ended up going with using 'ejs'. So easy controlling the back end this way and dom manipulation.
Why did that guy say this wasn't possible lol.

Comment: because, you're *still* not actually modifying the html from node, you're changing the output *before* it is sent to the client. (which is very useful/common, it's just not exactly what the user was trying to do)