# Making a server-side POST request with Node.js, Express, JQuery

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, ejs

I am fairly new to webdev so apologies if this is a dumb question. I am using Node.js, Express, and EJS, and I am trying to make a simple weather application to display the weather based on a zipcode. Retrieving and displaying the temperature has all gone fine. However, in an ideal world, since the temperature retrieval takes about 3-5 seconds, the user would be served a loading page in the interim, and then be served the temperature when the process has concluded. I am trying to do just this, but am struggling with the transition between the loading page and the page showing the temperature.

My current method of getting the temperature involves passing through the inputted zipcode to a javascript function getTemperature as follows:

**app.js (functional)**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const temperature = require('./temperature')
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log("LOG: GET request");
  res.render('pages/index', {output: "None"});
});

app.post('/',(req, res)=>{
  const {zipcode} = req.body;
  console.log("LOG: Received POST request with zip code " + zipcode);
  temperature.getTemperatureFromZipcode(res, zipcode);
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

**temperature.js (functional)**

```
function getTemperatureFromZipcode(res, zipcode) {
    // code omitted, finds the temperature via multiple API queries
    res.render('pages/index', {output: temperature});
```

This all works fine. However, to accomplish my goal of making the loading page, I would like to instead do something like this in app.js, where I serve a loading page when the first request is made, then myself make a POST request which does the work of getting the temperature - like this:

**app.js changes (not working)**

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM("");
const jQuery = require('jquery')(dom.window);

// repeated code omitted

app.post('/',(req, res)=>{
  const {zipcode} = req.body;
  console.log("LOG: Sending POST request with zip code " + zipcode);
  res.render('pages/index', {output: "Loading"});
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/request',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({"zipcode": zipcode }),
    success: function(response){ console.log( response ); }
  });
})

app.post('/request',(req, res)=> {
  console.log("LOG: Received POST request");
  const {zipcode} = req.body.zipcode; // this may be incorrect, but the code never got here so it's also irrelevant
  temperature.getTemperatureFromZipcode(res, zipcode); // makes a res.render call
})
```

However, when I try this, the first LOG (sending post request) appears fine, but I don't see anything for the second. It doesn't seem like the request is being made at all, because when I inspect my website and look at the 'Network' tab, I only see the first request. I also tried moving the code client-side (i.e. have the ajax call fire on the client side when the load page is rendered), but that didn't work either, with the same behavior as above.

Thus, my question is:
a) Why doesn't this work? (for my own understanding)
b) What is a better alternative? Open to any and all suggestions. This is something that I feel like has more use cases than just what I am trying to do, so I would appreciate any insight

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is a completely new project, the thing you're stuck on is the thing that [remix.js](https://remix.run/) solved at the fundamental level. Although it does mean giving up simple templating in favour of React (which may be too much of a change).

Comment: Make the AJAX request from your front-end, not the back-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own - thanks to Mike Kamermans for the suggestion (I'll look into it on another project!) and thanks to Phil for making me investigate the frontend more - that turned out to be the answer :)

Essentially, I changed it such that the loading page is rendered upon the initial POST request, and the zipcode is saved in the server. Then the loading page makes the ajax post request (so the request comes from the front-end), and it is received on the backend who calls getTemperature with the previously saved zipcode. Then getTemperature sends the temperature back to the page being loaded, who edits the HTML to include the new temperature.

Relevant code:

**app.js updates**

```
// repeated code omitted

app.post('/',(req, res)=>{
  const {zipcode} = req.body;
  console.log("LOG: Received zip code through POST request: " + zipcode)
  console.log("LOG: Rendering loader page");
  app.locals.zipcode = zipcode;
  console.log("LOG: Set global zip code to " + zipcode);
  res.render('pages/loader', {output: "Loading!"});
})

app.post('/request',(req, res)=> {
  console.log("LOG: Making request for zip code " + app.locals.zipcode);
  temperature.getTemperature(res, app.locals.zipcode);
})
```

**temperature.js**

```
function getTemperature(res, zipcode) {
    // make some API calls to get the temperature
    res.status(200).send(temperature);
}
```

**loader.ejs head**

```
<head>
    <%- include('../partials/head'); %>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({ 
                   url: '/request',
                   type: 'POST',
                   cache: false, 
                   data: {zipcode: "DONE"}, 
                   success: function(data){
                       document.querySelector("#output").innerHTML = data;
                   }
                   , error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
                        console.log('ERROR: text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
                    }
                })
           });            
    </script>
</head>
```

The reason the POST request from the front-end didn't work when I tried it previously was because I wasn't including jquery on the frontend.

I found this post to be very helpful in making this change - worth checking out: [How to change front-end html using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643522/how-to-change-front-end-html-using-node-js)